# Is it possible to save SESSION variable after a certain time passes?

Tags: php, session-variables

I want to save SESSION variable's content in database in 5 minutes after the content was saved in variable. How can I do that ? Is there a way to avoid cron ?

Comment: You could probably do this with a custom session handler that communicates with a server daemon process that keeps track of things. I don't know if there's anything canned to do this, you may have to implement it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the data in a table/file/whatever with a time stamp - but as you say, you'd need to cron it or some equivalent - an action can't be performed on a web page and then do something with session data 5 minutes later.

Unless they stay on the page and do an AJAX request or something like that.